# Taylor Approximation for two times differentiable functions

Tags: analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I have a very basic question, but if can't find a reasoning for the following problem. I found this expression in one of my lectures. Assume we have a function $f\in C^2([0,1])$
[image]

As you can see and neglect expectation, $Af(X)$ understand $X^N_1$ and $X$ just as elements in $[0,1]$, the author used a Taylor approximation for $f(X_1^N)-f(X)$.

In general, we have for Taylor with a Peano-error term:
$\xi \in [0,1]$
$f(x)= f(a)+ \frac{f'(a)}{1!}(x-a)+\frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2+\frac{f''(\xi)-f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2$

Is it possible to show that the error term $\frac{f''(\xi)-f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2$
is somehow bounded or of order of $||f''||_{\infty}(x-a)^3$ as in the above derivation?

I can't see, how we can express the error term with the power of $3$ and norm of $f''$.

Comment: Where do you find this expression? Do $f(X)$ and $\mathbb{E}_x$ represent some concepts in probability?

Comment: Yes, they do. $X$ is a Wright Fisher frequency process and the expectation is conditional on $X_0=x$

Comment: Sorry that I am not familiar with it and I am not able to help you.

Comment: No problem, but I think the probabilistic background is not helpful and it is just an analytical problem.

Comment: Since $f$ ranges  in $C^2([0,1])$ you can get any function from $C([0,1])$ for $f''$. Thus you cannot expect an estimate for $|f''(\xi)-f''(a)|$ better than the modulus of continuity of $f''$ at $a$, which is in general much worse than const$\cdot |\xi-a|$. I cannot say if the probabilistic setting is different for some reason, but I would try to check if the power of $3$ is a typo.

Comment: True, it has to be a typo or false argument, so obvious. If we just replace $f$ with second degree polynomial the equality can't hold. Unfortunately the power of 3 is necessary for further arguments in the lecture... 
Thanks a lot!